# (PYTHON) expresiones regulares para validación de contraseñas

Tags: python, contraseña

Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy haciendo un validador de contraseñas utilizando expresiones regulares. La contraseña para que sea correcta debe tener 8 caracteres, al menos una letra mayúscula y tiene que ser alfanumérica. Pero me da un error en el if anidado, no me doy cuenta en que estoy fallando. Cualquier ayuda o sugerencia se agradece enormemente!! :)

```
contrasenia=input("Ingrese clave: ")
if len(contrasenia)>=8:
    digito=re.compile(r'[0-9]+')
    num=digito.search(contrasenia)
    letra_may=re.compile(r'[A-Z]+')
    letraMay=letra_may.search(contrasenia)
    letra_min=re.compile(r'[a-z]+')
    letraMin=letra_min.search(contrasenia)

    if len(num)>=1 and len(letraMay)>=1 and len(letraMin)>=1:
        print("contraseña ok")

    else: 
        print(" no cumple requisitos")
else:
    print("contraseña con longitud invalida")
```

Comment: Cuál error? Por favor, edita la pregunta y pon la traza del error, tan completa como sea posible.

Comment: Si lo de usar expresiones regulares no es requisito, es más fácil comprobar las tres restricciones así: `len(contrasenia) == 8 and contrasenia != contrasenia.lower() and contrasenia.isalnum()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La cause del error es que `search` retorna `None` cuando falla o un `MatchObject` cuando encuentra lo buscado. Hay que preguntar simplemente por `valor retornado != None`

La compilación de expresiones regulares se hace una sola vez, para ahorrar tiempo durante el **uso** de la expresión. Por tal causa, sacó fuera la compilación:

```
import re

largo = re.compile(r'.{8,}')
digito = re.compile(r'\d+')
letra_may = re.compile(r'[A-Z]+')
letra_min = re.compile(r'[a-z]+')
```

También agregue un patrón que reconoce el largo mínimo. De esa manera ocupare expresiones regulares para todo.

Para cada expresión regular tengo un mensaje de error en caso de que falle. En esta tabla tengo una lista de tuplas asociando validación y mensaje:

```
validaciones = [(largo, "largo menor que ocho"),
                (digito, "no tiene digitos"),
                (letra_min, "no tiene letras minúsculas"),
                (letra_may, "no tiene letras mayúsculas")]
```

Para validar una contraseña recorro la lista aplicando cada patrón y emitiendo el mensaje de error cuando falle

```
valida = True
for validacion, mensaje in validaciones:
    if not validacion.search(test):
        print(f"{test}: {mensaje}")
        valida = False
```

Si el `for` termina sin encontrar errores, `valida` valdrá `True`.

#### Demo

```
import re

largo = re.compile(r'.{8,}')
digito = re.compile(r'\d+')
letra_may = re.compile(r'[A-Z]+')
letra_min = re.compile(r'[a-z]+')

validaciones = [(largo, "largo menor que ocho"),
                (digito, "no tiene digitos"),
                (letra_min, "no tiene letras minúsculas"),
                (letra_may, "no tiene letras mayúsculas")]

tests = [
    "1",
    "12345678",
    "abcedfgh",
    "ABCDEFGH",
    "Va-12-da"
]

for test in tests:
    valida = True
    for validacion, mensaje in validaciones:
        if not validacion.search(test):
            print(f"{test}: {mensaje}")
            valida = False

    if valida:
        print(f"{test} ok")
```

produce:

```
1: largo menor que ocho
1: no tiene letras minúsculas
1: no tiene letras mayúsculas
12345678: no tiene letras minúsculas
12345678: no tiene letras mayúsculas
abcedfgh: no tiene digitos
abcedfgh: no tiene letras mayúsculas
ABCDEFGH: no tiene digitos
ABCDEFGH: no tiene letras minúsculas
Va-12-da ok
```